# Can I use a vm to learn hacking instead of vps?

Tags: virtualization, vps

I just began learning ethica hacking from The Hacker Playbook 3, and the author uses AWS an amazon VPS. Can I use a vm using VirtualBox and follow up with the book without problems? Will I be able to do the same things as the author?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do they make you install Ubuntu or use Kali or something? A VPS is basically just a VM that someone else hosts, so if you can install whatever you need locally you can do everything in that instead. You may have a degraded user experience due to using weaker hardware though.

Comment: They are using Ubuntu

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing "special" with AWS servers. If you can obtain the same exact operating-system image, you could use virtualization and a shared (preferably internal only) network to configure the network as same as AWS environment